# How can I wrap my mobile website to access native mobile features?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, responsive-design

I would like to wrap my mobile website in a native shell. The reason for this is that I'd like to:

1. Allow my users to take pictures using the app via a link on the page, if they're using the wrapped native site.
2. Send push notifications to my users

Based on my initial research neither PhoneGap nor Titanium are really meant for this. What is the best strategy here? If it makes any difference, this is an enterprise app not a public app. I am only targeting Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So several months later I'm not sure why I thought PhoneGap and Titanium were poor choices, but they both would have worked fine, I'm sure. For a hybrid iOS app I ended up just using `UIWebView` with a native `UITabBar` and implementing some delegate methods on the web view to make it feel native.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not looking for something like Rhodes?

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build